# Rearrange buttons in a horizontal line

Tags: html, css, button

I am designing a website, and have these menu buttons which will act as like a banner near the top of the page for navigation.
However, at the moment on the website the buttons are in a vertical line. How do i make them horizontal?

here is the button:

```
 button1 {
 display: block;
 width: 175px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0.5rem auto;
 padding: 0.75rem;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 border:  solid #ffffff 2px;
 background: #8ec8ea;
 border-radius: 0.5rem;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

and my html where ive made the buttons..

```
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/"><button1>Home</button1></a></t>
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Facilities.html"><button1>Facilities</button1></a></t>
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Facilities.html"><button1>Facilities</button1></a></t>
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Donate.html"><button1>Donate</button1></a></t>
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/News.html"><button1>News</button1></a></t>
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Testimonials.html"><button1>Testimonials</button1></a></t>
<t><a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Contact.html"><button1>Contact us</button1></a></t>
```

Also, if there is better practice of doing this - let me know!

Comment: display:inline-block

Comment: That's no valid HTML. What is `<t>`? `<button1>` is no valid HTML tag.

Comment: What are `<t>` and `<button1>` object ? Because that doesn't exist in html. Do you use a framework or something like that to create your owns elements ?

Comment: <t> is just the font/size/colour of the text. 
<button1> is the new button ive made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` in your `button1` css

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/8wzgddhg/1/

And if you want a HTML W3C valid :

HTML:

```
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/" class="button1">
        Home
    </a>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Facilities.html" class="button1">
        Facilities
    </a>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Facilities.html" class="button1">
        Facilities
    </a>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Donate.html" class="button1">
        Donate
    </a>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/News.html" class="button1">
        News
    </a>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Testimonials.html" class="button1">
        Testimonials
    </a>
</div>
<div class="t">
    <a href="http://tv005382.webs.sse.reading.ac.uk/Lithium/3.-Lithium/app/Contact.html" class="button1">
        Contact us
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .button1 {
     width: 175px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin: 0.5rem auto;
     padding: 0.75rem;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     border: solid #ffffff 2px;
     background: #8ec8ea;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     outline: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
 .t {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/8wzgddhg/2/

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks!
(Never done html before so no idea what im doing!!)

Comment: @Easty I've just updated the my answer, you need to use valid HTML, you can't create your own HTML objects ! If your question is answered, please click on the tick on the correct answer to mark as resolved. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. :)